# php if expression using regex

Tags: php, regex

im trying to get any input-ed data to be replaced by the value '7', if it is not a number between 0 and 9.

Here's my code atm:

```
echo "Enter no. of days to search: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$days = fgets($handle);

$days2 = str_replace("\n", '', $days);

if ($days2 == '/^[0-9]{1}$/'){
    $days2 = "7";}
```

it doesnt replace any input (letters or numbers) with 7 though!
Help please! 
Thanks

Edit:

```
if ($days2 >= 0 && $days2 <= 9){
    }
else $days2 = "7";
```

works but only for numbers outside the range, not for if i input letters

Comment: Hey there will! Unfortunately this syntax is not right. You need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and/or http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: `if ($days2 < 0 || $days2 > 9){` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
 if (!is_numeric($days2) || $days2 > 9 || $days2 < 0){
     $days2 = "7";
 }
?>
```

This might be what you're looking for, without using any regex

Comment: No prob, dont forget to put your question as resolved ;)

Comment: @will http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: just click the "check" symbol on the left of my answer